# Spring REST input validation

Tags: spring, rest, validation, spring-mvc, bean-validation

I'm writing a REST service using Spring Boot and JPA. I need to be able to validate some of the input fields and I want to ensure I'm using a proper pattern for doing so.

Let's assume I have the following model and I also have no control over the model:

```
{
  "company"   : "ACME"
  "record_id" : "ACME-123"
  "pin"       : "12345"
  "company_name" : ""
  "record_type"  : 0
  "acl"          : ['View','Modify']
  "language"     : "E"
}
```

The things I need to do are:

1. Ensure the value is not empty - This seems simple enough using the @NotEmpty annotation and I can pass a message.
2. Ensure the value is part of a valid list of values - The example here is the language property in the model above. I want the value to be either E,F or S. This seems possible using a custom annotation (eg @ValidValue({"E","F","S"})) but is there a better/"Springy" way to do this?
3. Ensure the values in a list are part of a valid list of values - The example here is the acl property. Again this seems possible with a custom annotation like @ValidListValues({"View", "Modify", "Delete", "Hide"}) but same question as above.
4. Set a default value - From what I read, custom validator annotations are only able to validate and not modify. I would like to do something like @DefaultValue(value=5) if the value is null. Is this possible? More on this below.
5. Set a default value to the return of a static method - For example if the pin field in model above isn't set, I want to set it to something like Util.getRandomDigitsAsString(5).
6. Use values from another property - I would like to validate that one property contains the string from another property. Using the example model, I want to ensure that record_id starts with company.

I have this setup in what I believe is a standard way with the controller -> service -> DTO -> DAO -> Model. Another option I was thinking about was creating a method in the validateCreate() that would go through all of the items above and throw an exception if needed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, NotEmpty is the right way
2. You should define a `Language` enum. The language field of your POJO should be of type Language
3. Same as 2. Define an `Acl` enum.
4. Define that in your Java code. Initialize the value of the field to 5 by default. If the JSON contains a value, Jackson will set the field value to the value in the JSON. Otherwise, it will stay as 5. Or initialize the field to null, and add a method `getValueOrDefault(int defaultValue)` that returns the default value you want if the value is null.
5. Same as 4
6. Define a custom validator that applies on the class itself, rather than a property of the class. In the validator chec that the two related values are correct.

Comment: Thank you. I'll give all of these a shot. Should these be done in the DTO or the model?